# How to get address from lat and lng?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have two set of lat and lng.

I want both address and stored in some variable:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        for(var i=0; i<json_devices.length; i++)
        {
            var lat = json_devices[i].latitude;
            var lng = json_devices[i].longitude;
            console.log(lat);
            console.log(lng);
            var latlng =  new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
            geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
             if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              if (results[1]) {
                address=results[1].formatted_address;
                   } else {
                    alert('No results found');
                  }
                } else {
                  alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
                }
            });
            console.log(address);
        }
```

In this, lat & lan get correctly. But address are not stored in variable. What is the mistake?

Comment: can you create jsfiddle?

Comment: @VinceLowe here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Vz6m/28/) with rough data where the OP's question is reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this method and it is working perfect for me.
Please have a look on it.

```
public String getAddressFromLatLong(GeoPoint point) { 
        String address = "Address Not Found";
        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(
                getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(
                    point.getLatitudeE6()  / 1E6, 
                    point.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);

            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                            address =addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                if(address.length()<=0)
                address =addresses.get(0).getSubLocality();
                 }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {                
            e.printStackTrace();
             }   
        return address;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the Google geocode is **`asynchonous`** type of function call.

From [DOCS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding):

> Accessing the Geocoding service is asynchronous, since the Google Maps
>   API needs to make a call to an external server. For that reason, you
>   need to pass a callback method to execute upon completion of the
>   request. This callback method processes the result(s). Note that the
>   geocoder may return more than one result.

So you can't get the address like that, instead use the common approach called **`callback`**.

Here I have created a sample code to explain the process, which can be altered by yourself.

```
var geocoder;

function codeLatLng(callback) {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var input = document.getElementById("latlng").value;
    var latlngStr = input.split(",", 2);
    var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
    var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({
        'latLng': latlng
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[1]) {
                address = results[1].formatted_address;
                callback(address);
            } else {
                alert("No results found");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
        }
    });
}

$('input[type="button"]').on('click', function () {
    codeLatLng(function (address) { //function call with a callback
        console.log(address);  // THE ADDRESS WILL BE OBTAINED
    })
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Vz6m/27/)